# Using Xcode and getting error "Cannot assign to property: 'image' is a method

Tags: xcode

I'm new to coding and would really appreciate some help on this. I've searched everywhere for a fix to my issue, but can't find one that makes sense to me. Here's my code (error location noted). Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class UserVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate     {

@IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var completeSignUpBtn: UIButton!

var userUid: String!
var emailField: String!
var passwordField: String!
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
var imageSelected = false



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        userImagePicker.image = image **//error here**
        imageSelected = true
    }else {
        print("image wasn't selected")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func completeAccount (_ sender: Any){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion:
        {(user, error) in
            if error != nil {
            print(error)

            }else{
                if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.uid
                }
            }
        })
}

@IBAction func selectedImagePicker(_ sender: Any){
    present (imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func cancel (_ sender: AnyObject){
    dismiss (animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: if my answer helps you then please mark it as accepted else comment what you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly assign image to UIButton.  Button has different method to set images. Here is swift 3 sample code to set button image.

```
let playButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: .normal)
```

So try this

```
userImagePicker.setImage(image,for:.normal)
```

Comment: Thanksss! I reassigned it to UIImageView! and worked perfectly. I had used a button in the ViewController. So, changed it to an image view.

Comment: just tried that and it worked too. Thanks for the help!